# How to pick a property with the value in an array?

Tags: pluck

Here I have an array with many objects. In that I have a field as "id".
I want only the id which has a value as null. How to pick it?

```
$scope.hierarchyList = response.data;
```

So how to pluck the value?

Comment: What language scope of this question?

Answer (score 0):

it's quite complicate to answer if there's no way to know the structure of `response.data`. One way to do it (in case I understood) would be to:

```
var resultObj;
$scope.hierarchyList.forEach(function(hierarchy){
    if(hierarchy.id === undefined){
        resultObj = hierarchy; 
    }
})
```

please let me know if this is not the case or the question you're asking.